# How to find the similarities between combinations in a df?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, combinations

I have the following problem: I want to display the number of similar strings each combination of entities shares. My data is much larger than this in number of entities and strings but here's a simplified case:

```
Entity,String
X,A
X,B
Z,C
Z,A
Y,A
X,C
```

The result would look something like:

```
X:   3 (it has 3 distinct strings A/B/C)
Y:   1 (string A)
Z:   2 (strings A/C)
XY:  1 (X & Y only share string A)
XZ:  2 (X & Z share strings A & C)
YZ:  1 (X & Z only share string A)
XYZ: 1 (X,Y,Z only share string A)
```

Normally, if I had only two entities to compare, I would do a merge and count the number of both's. But now I have more entities than even this simplified case, in numerous combinations.

How can I most simply script this type of distinct counting for shared strings amongst entity combinations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [273]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[273]: 
  entity string
0      X      A
1      X      B
2      Z      C
3      Z      A
4      Y      A
5      X      C

In [274]: for c in range(1, len(df.entity.unique()) +1): 
     ...:     for combo in itertools.combinations(df.entity.unique(), c): 
     ...:         dfs = (df[df.entity == e] for e in combo) 
     ...:         a = set.intersection(*(set(f.string.unique()) for f in dfs)) 
     ...:         print(''.join(combo), len(a)) 
     ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
X 3
Z 2
Y 1
XZ 2
XY 1
ZY 1
XZY 1
```